# Visual Studio Keyboard shortcut to hide integrated terminal?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2022, we can show the integrated terminal via <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>.  However, the same key combination (with the integrated terminal in focus) does not then hide it when pressed again.  Is there another?  I checked [Keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/keyboard-shortcuts.pdf) you provided to the shortcuts has the following:

> Close Current Tool Window <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>esc</kbd>

<sub>"Shift" is illustrated with a ^ character, which is misleading in my opinion</sub>

I tested it and it does work.  The only small issue with this is you need to have the window focused.  This shortcut also should work with other windows as well.  If you want to remap this combination, it is called `Window.Close` in Tools → Options → Environment → Keyboard:

[image: window.close option in keyboard settings]

[*Visual Studio Mac*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/integrated-terminal?view=vsmac-2022) weirdly seems to support using the same shortcut to open and close the window however:

> Use the Ctrl + ` keyboard shortcut with the backtick character to show or hide the Terminal window.

Comment: I never would have guessed the integrated terminal was considered a tool window... thanks so much!

Comment: like the Visual Studio Mac discrepancy, also weird that Ctrl + ` twice works in Visual Studio Code on Windows!  ha!

Comment: @chrisxfire CTRL + J also works in Visual Studio Code to close/open the terminal